# How to make a function that takes in an array

Tags: arrays, r, function

I am making a function to take in a vector of colors and a 3x3x6 array. This is going to be a rubiks cube. I am using the function to see if the cube is solved or not. I am having trouble getting the function to use a color vector and array passed to it.

```
cube = function(color, cube){
  #Description:
  #Args:
  #Returns:
  array = array(color,cube)
  if(!dim(array)[1] == 3 | !dim(array)[2] == 3 | !dim(array)[3] == 6){
    print("Please enter a cube of 3 by 3 by 6")
  }
  if(!array[1] == 'red' | !array[2] == 'blue' | !array[3] == 'green' | 
  !array[4] == 'yellow' |     !array[5] == 'white' | !array[6] == 'orange'){
    print("Please enter a valid 6 colors for the cube")
  }
  #need more code here to check if the cube is solved
}

cube(c('red','blue','green','yellow','white','orange'), dim=c(3,3,6))
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
Error in cube(c('red','blue','green','yellow','white','orange'), dim = c(3, 3, 6)) : unused argument (dim = c(3, 3, 6))
```

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `dim=` when calling `cube(...)`

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `dim=` and pass in your `c(3,3,6)` directly.